# XSLT transform XML before import | issue with mapping

Tags: xml, xslt

This is example XML I need to import.

```
`<Products>
<Product id="ADEBLDADE0001" name="Black  Decker BL4018 Battery" producer="BLD" categoryId="ADE-ADE" warranty="F012M" priceNet="43.95" vat="23" vat_type="zwykły" pkwiu="27.20.23.0" externalWarehouse="N" available="30" date="2017-03-13" onOrder="N" specialOffer="N" lastChange="2022-10-17" smallPallet="N" productIsLarge="N" reported="T" EAN="5035048560044" manufacturerPartNumber="BL4018-XJ" sizeWidth="80" sizeLength="130" sizeHeight="110" weight="690" sizeMeasurementUnit="mm" weightMeasurementUnit="g" dimensionalWeight="228" additionalAvailabilityInfo="" expiryDate="1900-01-01" ETA="" incomingStock="0" mainCategoryTree="House and Garden" categoryTree="Tools - accessories" subCategoryTree="Batteries">
<Images>
<Image url="/Icecat/O2N59732L0C0C1V6o7K4N143m7O7K7A8.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
<Image url="/Icecat/I4B7m9t9K000X1b6w7V471A3H7R737c8.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
<Image url="/Icecat/O9P0t7g7k0k0E1s6H7O4u1R3H7c757V9.jpg" isMain="1" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
<Image url="/Icecat/I1P2w3a2c0r0N116X7E4P1a3n7l7w7q9.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
<Image url="/Icecat/T9X096A3D0D0T1d6A7h481i3B7P7A8L0.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
<Image url="/Icecat/Q1D233T3K020Z10607c421L3N7Z7Q8n1.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
<Image url="/Icecat/Z2X2z2e5s03031B6G7r4j1Z2W4C9B926.jpg" isMain="0" date="2023-01-19" copyright="0" />
</Images>
<Multimedia/>
<TechnicalSpecification>
<Section name="Features">
<Attributes>
<Attribute name="Product type">
<Values>
<Value Name="Battery"/>
</Values>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Battery technology">
<Values>
<Value Name="Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion)"/>
</Values>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Battery capacity">
<Values>
<Value Name="2 Ah"/>
</Values>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Battery voltage">
<Values>
<Value Name="18 V"/>
</Values>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Product colour">
<Values>
<Value Name="Grey"/>
<Value Name="Black"/>
<Value Name="Orange"/>
</Values>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="Number of batteries included">
<Values>
<Value Name="1 pc(s)"/>
</Values>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Section>
</TechnicalSpecification>
</Product>
</Products>`
```

But before import, I need to transform this XML using XSLT template. Now I start write XSLT template:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Products">
        
            <xsl:for-each select="Product">
                
                <xsl:element name="Product">
                    
                    <xsl:element name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    
                </xsl:element>
                
            </xsl:for-each>
            
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

But I have problem with transform this:

```
`<Product id="ADEBLDADE0001" name="Black  Decker BL4018 Battery" producer="BLD" categoryId="ADE-ADE" warranty="F012M" priceNet="43.95" vat="23" vat_type="zwykły" pkwiu="27.20.23.0" externalWarehouse="N" available="30" date="2017-03-13" onOrder="N" specialOffer="N" lastChange="2022-10-17" smallPallet="N" productIsLarge="N" reported="T" EAN="5035048560044" manufacturerPartNumber="BL4018-XJ" sizeWidth="80" sizeLength="130" sizeHeight="110" weight="690" sizeMeasurementUnit="mm" weightMeasurementUnit="g" dimensionalWeight="228" additionalAvailabilityInfo="" expiryDate="1900-01-01" ETA="" incomingStock="0" mainCategoryTree="House and Garden" categoryTree="Tools - accessories" subCategoryTree="Batteries">`
```

How Can I select tags inside one tag <product ? Can any one little help me or show any example code how can I do it?

udate@
except result:

I try convert to like:

```
    <Products>
<product>
    <id>ADEBLDADE0001</id>
    <name>Black  Decker BL4018 Battery</name>
    <producer>BLD</producer>
    <categoryId>ADE-ADE</categoryId>
    <warranty>F012M</warranty> 
    <priceNet>43.95</priceNet> 
    <vat>23</vat> 
    <vat_type>zwykły</vat_type> 
    <pkwiu>27.20.23.0</pkwiu> 
    <externalWarehouse>="N"</externalWarehouse> 
    <available>30</available> 
    <date>2017-03-13</date>
     <onOrder>N</onOrder> 
    <specialOffer>N</specialOffer>
     <lastChange>2022-10-17</lastChange> 
     <smallPallet>N</smallPallet>
     <productIsLarge>N</productIsLarge>
     <reported>T</reported> 
     <EAN>5035048560044</EAN> 
     <manufacturerPartNumber>BL4018-XJ</manufacturerPartNumber>
     <sizeWidth>80</sizeWidth>
     <sizeLength>130</sizeLength>
     <sizeHeight>110</sizeHeight>
     <weight>690</weight>
     <sizeMeasurementUnit>mm</sizeMeasurementUnit>
     <weightMeasurementUnit>g"</weightMeasurementUnit>
     <dimensionalWeight>228</dimensionalWeight>
     <additionalAvailabilityInfo> </additionalAvailabilityInfo>
     <expiryDate>1900-01-01</expiryDate>
     <ETA></ETA>
     <incomingStock>0 </incomingStock>
     <mainCategoryTree>House and Garden </mainCategoryTree>
     <categoryTree>Tools - accessories </categoryTree>
     <subCategoryTree>Batteries></subCategoryTree>
    <Image_main>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_main>
    <Image_extra_1>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_1>
    <Image_extra_2>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_2>
    <Image_extra_3>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_3>
    <Image_extra_4>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_4>
    <Image_extra_5>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_5>
    <Image_extra_6>/Icecat/S0p7v4R77040m1G5A8J41445s6v7T2v9.jpg</Image_extra_6>
    <Product_type>Battery</Product_type>
    <Battery_technology>Lithium-Ion (Li-Ion)</Battery_technology>
    <Battery_capacity>2 Ah</Battery_capacity>
    <Battery_voltage>18 V</Battery_voltage>
    <Product_colour>Grey Black Orange</Product_colour>
    <Number_of_batteries_included>1 pc(s)</Number_of_batteries_included>
    </Product>
    </Products>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Note also that the input you show in your question contains an unescaped `&` character.  This is not allowed in XML and such input cannot be processed by XSLT at all.

Comment: The "tags inside one tag" are called attributes. Any XSLT tutorial will teach you how to select them.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks for information. Ok I delete this & character. And also I update with sample except result.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear. Post one result, not two.

Answer (score 1):

To convert all attributes of a `Product` to elements you can do simply:

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="Product">
    <Product>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
        <!-- other data here -->
        
    </Product>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

As noted correctly in the comments, this is a trivial problem and you should have known the answer if you had spent an hour or less with a XSLT book or tutorial.

Comment: yes, now I do it. Please see screenshot. Currently still I have problem with only this  part 2 code, with num tags with images and attributes  writing like <Attribute name="Battery capacity">
<Values>
<Value Name="2 Ah"/>
</Values>
</Attribute> https://prnt.sc/U-EwzX4wWELM